# MSN history XML and XSL in Chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt, msn-messenger

**I want to show MSN history in Chrome.** As far as I know these XML files works with a XSL file next to them as all history xml has the xsl file as stylesheet. Every browser (IE6-7-8,Opera,Firefox 4 beta, Safari (even on iPod)) opens the XML file and show it as a big `<table>` as it styled in the xsl file, but Chrome only creates an empty pages with no error message and it works on it 1 second, no matter the file is a full history (about 1mb in size).

Is it Chrome's error or the XSL is bad (but why every other browser opens it then?).

The xsl file: MessageLog.xsl is the stylesheet, you can find it in the folder where MSN history xml's are saved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981524/how-can-i-make-xslt-work-in-chrome

Comment: @Phil: There are some wrong assumptions on that question. Chrome refuse to open `file:///` protocol stylesheets.

Comment: Another problem caused by a lack of `--allow-file-access-from-files`?

Comment: @Phil I found that question too (google find it :P) but non of those solutions solved this problem for me.

Comment: @Alejandro Then this can be the cause? Chrome simply refuse it to open?

Comment: The exact message is  `Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:test.xsl from frame with URL file:///C:test.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Answer (score 0):

The local XML cannot reference the local XSLT. Upload the MSN History to a web server, or use a [self-invoked stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868699/) to workaround this in Chrome.